# Create a function similar to mnist.train.next_batch(128) for custom image data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, training-data

I am trying to implement the function: `batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(128)` for my dataset of images.

For training, I have 1000 folders (the name of the folder is the same as which class it belongs to "Class1", "Class2", "Class3" and so on).  Each of these folders conatain 500 images belonging to a single class.

So in all, I have 500,000 images which have to be trained.

What is the best way for me to divide them into batches (where images are randomly selected) and feed to my inference model?

I am not using Keras, and using Tensorflow 1.15.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
import numpy as np
import os
import pathlib
tf.__version__

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 128
IMG_WIDTH = 128
IMG_HEIGHT = 256
DATA_DIR = 'D:/PythonWorkspace/train'
DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path(DATA_DIR) #RD

def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES

def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # Use `convert_image_dtype` to convert to floats in the [0,1] range.
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  # resize the image to the desired size.
  return tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

#aataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.path.join(DATA_DIR,'*/*'))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(DATA_DIR/'*/*')) #RD
for f in dataset.take(5):
  print(f.numpy())
dataset = dataset.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Output:

```
'1.15.2'

b'D:\\PythonWorkspace\\train\\1403\\5T04015F015.jpg'
b'D:\\PythonWorkspace\\train\\0525\\C3T0020F097.jpg'
b'D:\\PythonWorkspace\\train\\0005\\24T0060F004.jpg'
b'D:\\PythonWorkspace\\train\\1159\\45T0008F041.jpg'
b'D:\\PythonWorkspace\\train\\0425\\C5T0021F007.jpg'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b683dfeb641b> in <module>
     32 for f in dataset.take(5):
     33   print(f.numpy())
---> 34 dataset = dataset.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
     35 dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE)
     36 dataset = dataset.repeat()

....
....
....
AttributeError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-2-b683dfeb641b>:24 process_path  *
        label = get_label(file_path)
    <ipython-input-2-b683dfeb641b>:11 get_label  *
        parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    d:\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\ragged\ragged_string_ops.py:642 strings_split_v1
        return ragged_result.to_sparse()

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'to_sparse'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tf.data` to build a pipeline. For example something like the following, courtesy of the [tf.data guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images):

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 128
IMG_WIDTH = 128
IMG_HEIGHT = 128
DATA_DIR = <Your data dir>

def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES

def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # Use `convert_image_dtype` to convert to floats in the [0,1] range.
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  # resize the image to the desired size.
  return tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(DATA_DIR/'*/*'))
dataset = dataset.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

The resulting `dataset` would then return batches of random images and their labels.

Comment: I used `DATA_DIR = 'D:\PythonWorkspace\TrainImages'` But there's an error: `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'` in the line: `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(DATA_DIR/'*/*')) `

Comment: Can you try `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, '*/*'))`? You have to `import os` first.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed that particular issue, but I got another error (as described in my question above)

Comment: From the output you posted, it seems like there is a problem with the way the file paths are formatted. `tf.strings.split` only expects one `os.path.sep` here